# Is there a way to vectorize adding missing months using resample?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, vectorization, pandas-resample

I am trying to add missing months for each `ID`. Added months should have info on `ID` and `year_month`, and NaN for Product. My code achieves this using `apply()`, but is slow -- I am looking for a vectorized version, which can run significantly faster.

Specifically, `df.set_index(df.index).groupby('ID').apply(add_missing_months)` takes about 20 seconds on my system with 60 000 rows. I plan to work with data with millions of rows, so I think I need to vectorize the operation. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'year_month': ['2020-01-01','2020-08-01','2020-10-01','2020-01-01','2020-07-01','2021-05-01'], 'product':['A','B','C','A','D','C']})

# Enlarge dataset to 60 000 rows
for i in range(9999):
    df2 = df.iloc[-6:].copy()
    df2['ID'] = df2['ID'] + 3
    df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df['year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'], format = '%Y%m%d')
df = df.drop('year_month', axis = 1)

# The slow function
def add_missing_months(s):
    min_d = s.index.min()
    max_d = s.index.max()
    s = s.reindex(pd.date_range(min_d, max_d, freq='MS'))
    return(s)

df = df.set_index(df.index).groupby('ID').apply(add_missing_months)
df = df.drop('ID', axis = 1)
df = df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if faster, but simplier code is:

```
df = df.sort_index().groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('MS'))
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('MS'))
df2 = df.set_index(df.index).groupby('ID').apply(add_missing_months)

print (df1.equals(df2))
True
```

EDIT: For improve performance is create month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), aggregate minimal and maximal value with get difference of them with repeat indices by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), last add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) foa append months ranges, convert to timestamps by [`Series.dt.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_timestamp.html) and last use left join:

```
df1 = (df.assign(year_month = df['year_month'].dt.to_period('m'))
         .groupby(['ID'])['year_month']
         .agg(['min', 'max']))

diff = df1['max'].astype('int').sub(df1['min'].astype('int')) + 1
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(diff)]
df1 = (df1['min'].add(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()))
                 .dt.to_timestamp()
                 .reset_index(name='year_month'))

df = df1.merge(df.rename_axis(None), how='left')
```

**Performance**:

```
In [276]: %timeit jez(df)
126 ms ± 7.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [277]: %timeit vogel(df)
312 ms ± 32.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'year_month': ['2020-01-01','2020-08-01','2020-10-01','2020-01-01','2020-07-01','2021-05-01'], 'product':['A','B','C','A','D','C']})

# Enlarge dataset to 60 000 rows
for i in range(9999):
    df2 = df.iloc[-6:].copy()
    df2['ID'] = df2['ID'] + 3
    df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df['year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'], format = '%Y%m%d')

def jez(df):

    df1 = df.assign(year_month = df['year_month'].dt.to_period('m')).groupby(['ID'])['year_month'].agg(['min', 'max'])
    df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat( df1['max'].astype('int').sub(df1['min'].astype('int')) + 1)]
    df1 = (df1['min'] +  df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).dt.to_timestamp().reset_index(name='year_month')
    
    return df1.merge(df.rename_axis(None), how='left')
```

---

```
def vogel(df):
    min_d = df['year_month'].min()
    max_d = df['year_month'].max()
    
    # generate all possible combinations of date and ID
    df_agg = df.groupby(['ID'])['year_month'].agg(['min', 'max'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
            [pd.date_range(min_d, max_d, freq='MS'), df_agg.index]
        )
    )
    
    # reduce to only relevant dates
    df = df.merge(df_agg, left_on='ID', right_index=True)
    df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'year_month'})
    df = df[df['year_month'].between(df['min'], df['max'])]
    df = df.drop(columns=['min', 'max'])
    
    # add product information
    df = df.merge(df, how='left')
        
    return  df
```

Comment: I confirm this gives the same result (and is simpler), but the runtime is only slightly faster -- from 18.5 to 17.5 seconds on my system. Do you know if a vectorized version might exist? Thank you!

Comment: @Dudelstein - I try `df.groupby('ID').resample('MS').first()` - but it si slowiest

Comment: @Dudelstein - You can probably use multiprocessing wrapper like pandarallel over the code added here by jezrael and get a better run time. See pandarallel docs here : https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/

Comment: Incredible, 0.11 seconds, so >150 faster than before, thank you! @SreeramTP I think parallel is a good idea, although I'm pretty sure it could not beat the vector solution.

Answer (score 1):

The code is a lot more convoluted and could probably be improved a bit, but it does seem to be much faster (down from 16 to 0.2 seconds on my system, starting from `# my code starts here`):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'year_month': ['2020-01-01','2020-08-01','2020-10-01','2020-01-01','2020-07-01','2021-05-01'], 'product':['A','B','C','A','D','C']})

# Enlarge dataset to 60 000 rows
for i in range(9999):
    df2 = df.iloc[-6:].copy()
    df2['ID'] = df2['ID'] + 3
    df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df['year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'])

# my code starts here
# find overall min and max date
min_d = df['year_month'].min()
max_d = df['year_month'].max()

# generate all possible combinations of date and ID
df_agg = df.groupby(['ID'])['year_month'].agg(['min', 'max'])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [pd.date_range(min_d, max_d, freq='MS'), df_agg.index]
    )
)

# reduce to only relevant dates
df = df.merge(df_agg, left_on='ID', right_index=True)
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'year_month'})
df = df[df['year_month'].between(df['min'], df['max'])]
df = df.drop(columns=['min', 'max'])

# add product information
df = df.merge(df, how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer -- it is really good, I chose jezrael's answer since it's a bit faster and uses less RAM, since the min and max dates are done for each ID separately.